# Default value in C++ depending on other input argument

Tags: c++, default-value

It looks like something like this in the declaration is not possible:

```
void func(float a, int b=int(a+1)){/*do stuff*/}
```

Basically, I want the default value of `b` depending on `a`. Is there a proper workaround for this, besides overloading `func`?

Comment: I would like to call it either with `func(a)` (then the default value should be assigned) or with `func(a,b)`.

Comment: why dont you want an overload? it would be as simple as `void func(float a) { func(a,a+1); }`

Comment: @tobi303 I thought so too that is is an overload.

Comment: other option may be assigning some invalid default value to `b` and then in function check for it and reassign some desired value to `b`

Comment: @Satus what is an "invalid default value" ? How would you make sure that for some caller that value isnt a valid value that he would like to pass?

Comment: @tobi303 in my problem there is constraint on `b` I didn't post, so I can assign an invalid default value I guess.

Comment: @tobi303 for example, if he expects only positive values, he can assign default `-1` and then, inside `func`, check for it and assign `a+1` to `b`. As I said, it is just another option, but I'd say that overloading is a better option.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think overloading is the way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Overloading: One function taking only `a` as an argument, and it in turn call another function passing two arguments.

Something like

```
void func(float a, int b)
{
    // Do stuff...
}

void func(float a)
{
    func(a, static_cast<int>(a) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know why you use `static_cast<int>(a) + 1`? Simply using `(int) a + 1` will work too, right?

Comment: To cast `float a` to `int`

Comment: @AnandS C-style casts are possibly dangerous, using [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) will let the compiler check that the cast is possible. in such a simple case as this it doesn't really matter, but using [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) instead of C-style casts or function-style casts (e.g. `int(a)`) everywhere is a good habit, and good habits should be maintained everywhere or it's no longer a habit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'll keep that in mind - thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement what @tobi303 mentioned. But if you really want 2 separate variables, you can also implement the following:

```
void func(float a)
{
    int b = (int)a + 1;
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Overloading is also possible:

```
void func(float a, int b)
{
    // Do stuff...
}

void func(float a)
{
    func(a, (int)a + 1);
}
```